# pyodbc.OperationalError: SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] ODBC SQL Server Driver][

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have searched the web all day tried many solutions but none works. I can manually connect to this server but not with Python I get this error:

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
>   (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (5); [08001]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
>   (0)')

I have tried the following:

- A)

  ```
  cnx = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{SQL Server}',
                       SERVER=self.DBserver,
                       DATABASE=xyz,
                       username=self.DBusername,
                       password=self.DBpassword,
                       PORT = 1433)
  ```
- B)

  ```
  cnx = pyodbc.connect('''Driver={SQL Server}; 
                       SERVER=tcp:<self.DBserver>; 
                       PORT=self.DBPort; DATABASE=xyz; 
                       UID=self.DBusername; 
                       PWD=self.DBpassword''')
  ```
- C)

  ```
  cnx = = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{SQL Server}',
                         SERVER=self.DBserver,
                         DATABASE=xyz,
                         UID=self.DBusername,
                         PWD=self.DBpassword)
  ```

Comment: Your second example won't work as written because you will be passing the literal `self.DBusername` not the value of that property. However, your second example *does* use the correct attribute names `UID=` and `PWD=`. Also, Microsoft's ODBC drivers **do not** use `PORT=`, but you've shown the port as 1433 so it presumably doesn't matter because that's the default. Try your second approach using an `f'''string'''` and see if that helps.

Comment: so i added A, B, C tries the try C above is your suggestion that didnt help . Unless I didnt understand your approach

Comment: Try hard-coding parameter values. It might the `self` variables do not propagate.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with firewall. it is working now

Comment: Next time, try to connect with a client tool like SSMS, Azure Data Studio (despite the name, it's VS Code for databases) or [mssql-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli?view=sql-server-ver15). Most of the time, the error is right

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need something more like this:

```
cnx = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+self.DBserver+';DATABASE=xyz;UID='+self.DBusername+';PWD='+self.DBpassword)
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when trying to connect to Azure SQL Server with pyodbc (4.0.30) when connected via VPN and running in Windows Subsystem for Linux:

```py
with pyodbc.connect(db_connect_string) as conn:
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x274C (10060) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

The Python code is running in WSL (5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2) / Ubuntu 20.04.3, `openssl version` shows: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021

I could successfully connect with the same credentials via:

- MS Data Studio with VPN
- same Python/pyodbc code in Powershell with VPN
- same Python/pyodbc code in WSL without VPN (plus adding a firewall rule)

My guess is there must be some interaction between OpenSSL and our] VPN, possibly related to these issues.

- https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/853
- https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1112

Comment: Leaving this here for others trying to solve similar issues... or myself next time. :)